# Content padding in custom view with Cocoa auto layout

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, autolayout

I have a custom `NSView` subclass which has a border around itself. The border is drawn inside this view. Is it possible to respect this borders with auto layout?

For example, when I place the subview to my custom view and set constraints like this:

```
@"H:|-(myViewSubView)-|" (not @"H:|-(myViewBorderWidth)-(myViewSubView)-(myViewBorderWidth)-|")
@"V:|-(myViewSubView)-|"
```

the layout must be:

```
Horizontal: |-(myViewBorderWidth)-|myViewSubview|-(myViewBorderWidth)-|
  Vertical: |-(myViewBorderWidth)-|myViewSubview|-(myViewBorderWidth)-|
```

I've tried to overwrite `-bounds` method in my view to return the bounds rect without the borders, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one solution I found is to overload the `addConstraint:` method and modify constraints before they'll be added:

```
- (void)addConstraint:(NSLayoutConstraint *)constraint
{
    if(constraint.firstItem == self || constraint.secondItem == self) {
        if(constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeLeading) {
            constraint.constant += self.leftBorderWidth;
        } else if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeTrailing) {
            constraint.constant += self.rightBorderWidth;
        } else if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeTop) {
            constraint.constant += self.topBorderWidth;
        } else if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeBottom) {
            constraint.constant += self.bottomBorderWidth;
        }
    }

    [super addConstraint:constraint];
}
```

And then also handle this constraints in `xxxBorderWidth` setters.

Answer (score 2):

#### UPDATE

I just noticed that your question is talking about `NSView` (OS X), not `UIView` (iOS).  Well, this idea should still be applicable, but you won't be able to drop my code into your project unchanged.  Sorry.

#### ORIGINAL

Consider changing your view hierarchy.  Let's say your custom bordered view is called `BorderView`.  Right now you're adding subviews directly to `BorderView` and creating constraints between the `BorderView`  and its subviews.

Instead, give the `BorderView` a single subview, which it exposes in its `contentView` property.  Add your subviews to the `contentView` instead of directly to the `BorderView`.  Then the `BorderView` can lay out its `contentView` however it needs to.  This is how `UITableViewCell` works.

Here's an example:

```
@interface BorderView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
@property (nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets borderSize;

@end
```

If we're using a xib, then we have the problem that IB doesn't know that it should add subviews to the `contentView` instead of directly to the `BorderView`.  (It does know this for `UITableViewCell`.)  To work around that, I've made `contentView` an outlet.  That way, we can create a separate, top-level view to use as the content view, and connect it to the `BorderView`'s `contentView` outlet.

To implement `BorderView` this way, we'll need an instance variable for each of the four constraints between the `BorderView` and its `contentView`:

```
@implementation BorderView {
    NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint;
    NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint;
    NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint;
    NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint;
    UIView *_contentView;
}
```

The `contentView` accessor can create the content view on demand:

```
#pragma mark - Public API

- (UIView *)contentView {
    if (!_contentView) {
        [self createContentView];
    }
    return _contentView;
}
```

And the setter can replace an existing content view, if there is one:

```
- (void)setContentView:(UIView *)contentView {
    if (_contentView) {
        [self destroyContentView];
    }
    _contentView = contentView;
    [self addSubview:contentView];
}
```

The `borderSize` setter needs to arrange for the constraints to be updated and for the border to be redrawn:

```
- (void)setBorderSize:(UIEdgeInsets)borderSize {
    if (!UIEdgeInsetsEqualToEdgeInsets(borderSize, _borderSize)) {
        _borderSize = borderSize;
        [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

We'll need to draw the border in `drawRect:`.  I'll just fill it with red:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:bounds];
    [path appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, self.borderSize)]];
    path.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;
    [path addClip];
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(bounds);
}
```

Creating the content view is trivial:

```
-  (void)createContentView {
    _contentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [self addSubview:_contentView];
}
```

Destroying it is slightly more involved:

```
- (void)destroyContentView {
    [_contentView removeFromSuperview];
    _contentView = nil;
    [self removeConstraint:topConstraint];
    topConstraint = nil;
    [self removeConstraint:leftConstraint];
    leftConstraint = nil;
    [self removeConstraint:bottomConstraint];
    bottomConstraint = nil;
    [self removeConstraint:rightConstraint];
    rightConstraint = nil;
}
```

The system will automatically call `updateConstraints` before doing layout and drawing if somebody has called `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`, which we did in `setBorderSize:`.  In `updateConstraints`, we'll create the constraints if necessary, and update their constants based on `borderSize`.  We also tell the system not to translate the autoresizing masks into constraints, because that tends to create unsatisfiable constraints.

```
- (void)updateConstraints {
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [super updateConstraints];
    if (!topConstraint) {
        [self createContentViewConstraints];
    }
    topConstraint.constant = _borderSize.top;
    leftConstraint.constant = _borderSize.left;
    bottomConstraint.constant = -_borderSize.bottom;
    rightConstraint.constant = -_borderSize.right;
}
```

All four constraints are created the same way, so we'll use a helper method:

```
- (void)createContentViewConstraints {
    topConstraint = [self constrainContentViewAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop];
    leftConstraint = [self constrainContentViewAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft];
    bottomConstraint = [self constrainContentViewAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom];
    rightConstraint = [self constrainContentViewAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight];
}

- (NSLayoutConstraint *)constrainContentViewAttribute:(NSLayoutAttribute)attribute {
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_contentView attribute:attribute relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:attribute multiplier:1 constant:0];
    [self addConstraint:constraint];
    return constraint;
}

@end
```

I have put a complete working example in [this git repository](https://github.com/mayoff/stackoverflow-15850543-BorderView-managing-contentView-and-constraints).

Comment: Thank you for this example! But in my case this view is a very very base class for other views in my framework, that's why it's not a good idea to change view hierarchy..

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you can override `NSView.alignmentRectInsets` to affect the position of the layout guides:

> **Custom views that draw ornamentation** around their content can override
>   this property and return insets that align with the edges of the
>   content, excluding the ornamentation. This allows the constraint-based
>   layout system to align views based on their content, rather than just
>   their frame.

Link to documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1526870-alignmentrectinsets

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the intrinsic size to include the border size?

```
- (NSSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    return NSMakeSize(width+bordersize, height+bordersize);
}
```

then you would set the content compression resistance priorities in both directions to be required:

```
[self setContentCompressionResistancePriority:NSLayoutPriorityRequired forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintHorizontal];
[self setContentCompressionResistancePriority:NSLayoutPriorityRequired forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintVertical];
```

Comment: `intrinsicContentSize` defines the size of the view in its superview, but I need to set the internal paddings for my view

Comment: But surely "the size of the view in its super view" should include the internal padding

Comment: Yes of course, but my problem is to position subviews in my view, not my view in its superview

Comment: Oh, I thought your problem was that the superview wasn't giving your view the requested border. Why can't you just layout your subviews with `|-(bordersize)-[subview]-(bordersize)-|`, which would seem to be the obvious solution

Comment: This view is base superclass which has a lot of subclasses in my project, that's why I want it to control its internal layout by itself