# Set a margin on NSView

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is it possible to set margins on a `NSView`?

On iOS I'm using the property `directionalLayoutMargins` on a UIView.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Content padding in custom view with Cocoa auto layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850543/content-padding-in-custom-view-with-cocoa-auto-layout)

Comment: Or maybe it's easier to use a subview.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks. Wrapping by a view just for this is not OK I think. I see the solutions there use either AutoLayout or require subclassing the view. There's no way to do this by other ways? (as I mentioned, for example iOS has `directionalLayoutMargins`). For instance, how do I add margin to a child inside a NSStackView?

Comment: Also that question is about padding not margin. Margin does not affect in any way size, either outer size or inner size

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot/mockup of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `NSView` doesn't have margins. `NSStackView` has `edgeInsets`.

Comment: @Tritonal I need to find a general way (function if you want) to be able to set margins on any NSView. Think of margins like how it works in CSS.

Comment: @Willeke correct, I should have mentioned I'm thinking of how margin works in CSS

Comment: For example, I want to set a 10, 5, 10, 5 (left, top, right, bottom) margin on a NSView. In a NSStackView I will see the NSView with that margin around it in respect to the parent NSStackView and to any other NSView inside the NSStackView

Comment: You can do this by constraints I think, but I was looking for another way than AutoLayout

Comment: `NSStackView` has `edgeInsets` and `spacing` - could this help you? So instead of setting a margin for the `NSView`, set an inset for the container.

Comment: @Tritonal I have multiple child views, not just one. I want to set margin on the actual view